Hausdorff distance and Hausdorff measure of symmetric difference
Let $X_n$ be a sequence of $k$-dimensional piecewise smooth submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^m$, converging in Hausdorff distance to a $k$-dimensional piecewise smooth submanifold $Y \subset \mathbb{R}^m$, where $k \leq m$. Is it necessarily true that $H^k(X_n) \to H^k(Y)?$
Here $H^k$ denotes the $k^{\mathrm{th}}$-Hausdorff measure. For convenience, we can assume that all $X_n$ and $Y$ are compact. I suspect this must be well-known to experts, so this is mainly a reference request.

No. For a trivial example, consider concentric circles with radii $r_n=1-1/n$.

@JochenWengenroth Thanks, I realized that this was not written properly. I have edited the question.

Take any manifold $Y$ and approximate it by a sawtooth of higher and higher frequency but lower and lower height. This way you can even get $H^k(X_n) \to \infty$ and still have convergence in the Hausdorff distance.

@mlk This is nice, thanks! But what if we add curvature bounds? Is something known then?

Controlling curvature avoids that problem, assuming you also upgrade piecewise smooth to smooth. But there is also multiplicity. Take $X_n$ to be two different disjoint manifolds both converging to same limit, then the Hausdorff limit is just one copy of the limit. You can even do the same with a connected manifold by taking the boundary of a Möbius-strip of width $1/n$, which converges to a single circle.
